Solve Recurrence Relation with Master theorem Case 3
I need your help with the following problem:
I’m supposed to find a simple function $ g(n) $ for the recurrence relation
$ T(n) = 9 \cdot T\left( \lceil \frac{n}{4} \rceil \right) + 3^n $
with the base conditions $ T(2) = T(1) = 1 $, such that $ T(n) = \Theta(g(n)) $.
To do this, I use the Master Theorem. According to it:
$ a = 9 $
$ b = 4 $
$ f(n) = 3^n $
The recursive part yields $ n^{\log_b a} = n^{\log_4 9} $.
The non-recursive part is $ f(n) = 3^n $.
Since $ f(n) = 3^n $ grows exponentially and $ n^{\log_4 9} $ only grows polynomially, it is clear that $ f(n) $ dominates, and thus case 3 of the Master Theorem must be applied. To show this, the following must hold:
$ f(n) = \Omega(n^{\log_b a + \epsilon}) $
This means there exists a constant $ a \in \mathbb{R}^+ $ and an $ n_0 \in \mathbb{N} $ such that for all $ n \geq n_0 $:
$ 3^n \geq a \cdot n^{\log_4 9 + \epsilon} $
Choosing $ \epsilon = 1 $ and $ a = 1 $, the statement holds, and we have:
$ f(n) = 3^n \in \Omega(n^{\log_4 9 + 1}) $
Now it must also be shown that there exists a constant $ c < 1 $ such that the following inequality holds for sufficiently large $ n $:
$ 9 \cdot f\left( \frac{n}{4} \right) \leq c \cdot f(n) $
At this point, I’m stuck and struggling to show that
$ 9 \cdot 3^{n/4} \leq c \cdot 3^n $
is true.
I wanted to prove it using successive approximations but couldn’t really find a solution.
